# iOS contact permissions disappeared automatically on production

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

We have a React Native app on the App store (iOS) which was asking users for contact permissions till yesterday. Suddenly we are seeing it isn't asking for contact permissions anymore. Even if we search for that app in the settings, the permissions are not present. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: any code on how youre asking for permission?

Comment: with the Info.plist fle

Comment: Simply having the reason string in your info.plist won't trigger the request for contacts access and make the permission available in settings.  Your code needs to request contacts access.  If it isn't asking for permission you won't see a request.

Comment: That code is present. It was working till yesterday. Today I am not able to see that contact permission option when I go into settings.

Comment: If th permission request isn't shown then you aren't asking for permissions [edit] your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: The permissions were being asked during onboarding and for old accounts, they were skipping the process which didn't show the popup. Have started asking for permissions on home screen now. The issue is fixed. Thank you all for the help.